# What is the use of Stack Overflow badges?

Tags: discussion, badges

What is the use of Stack Overflow badges? Do we get points or new provisions for each badge? Or are they just for fun and encouragement?

Comment: If you have a gold tag badge you can close questions of that tag as duplicates by yourself (without the need for more votes).